# Assign an icon to a category post

Tags: categories

Is there a way to assign an icon to a category post as well as the posts original image that's set in the featured images?

So if had a post about grapes I would have an image of some grapes in the thumbnail but I'd also have a grape icon from the grapes category attached to the preview post. This is an example of what I mean http://wordpress.thebebel.com/showcase/bloggaexport/

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see from the link you mentioned, there are no icons for categories, only avatars for authors. Is that what you mean? If you do want category icons, take a look at some plugins in the WordPress.org directory. Here's an example: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/category-icons/

Comment: Sorry that's probably me misinterpreting that author avatars as categories. Thanks for the links I'll check those out if I can't do Miha's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You could do that in template. Have an array of `$category_icons = (category_id => url_to_icon,…)` and then where you want to show the icon, you just use `<img src="<?$category_icons[$cat_id]?>">` where `$cat_id` would be the current category ID.

Comment: Cool thanks Miha, I'll give that go and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a plugin such as this:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/taxonomy-images/

These plugins work by adding a term meta table, then adding a meta key/value holding the ID of an attachment, the same way featured images work with posts, but for taxonomy terms

Answer (score 0):

You could also set a background image with the auto-generated css class `category-slug` in your stylesheet

Comment: Please elaborate how this would be "auto generated".